# Compare multiple numbers row by row of same table in teradata

Tags: teradata

Here is my table data from which I want to assign values to the record.

```
     Member_ID |    Claim_ID |    Codes     |  Pull

       123     |     Y   |  12,23,35,78 |   Y

       123     |     N   |     12,35    |   Y

       123     |     N   |     23,34    |   N

       123     |     N   |     33,34    |   N
```

I am using the teradata to assign 'Y' or 'N' to Pull depending on the codes and claims.

```
     SEL A.MEMBER_ID,A.CLAIM_ID,A.CODES,
     'Y' AS PULL
     FROM (SEL * FROM DBC.PULL_COMP WHERE CLAIM_ID='Y') A
     INNER JOIN ((SEL * FROM DBC.PULL_COMP WHERE CLAIM_ID='N') B
     ON A.MEMBER_ID=B.MEMBER_ID
     UNION
     SEL B.MEMBER_ID,B.CLAIM_ID,B.CODES,
     CASE WHEN OREPLACE(A.CODES,B.CODES,B.CODES)=A.CODES THEN 'Y'
     ELSE 'N' END AS PULL
     FROM (SEL * FROM DBC.PULL_COMP WHERE CLAIM_ID='Y') A
     INNER JOIN ((SEL * FROM DBC.PULL_COMP WHERE CLAIM_ID='N') B
     ON A.MEMBER_ID=B.MEMBER_ID
```

If the Claim_id is 'Y' the Pull will remain 'Y'. I want to compare the records whose claim_id is 'Y' with those whose claim_id id 'N'. The second record contains no new numbers when comparing with 1st record so Pull='Y'. The 3rd record contains one new number(34) hence Pull='N'. The 4th record contains all new numbers compared to 1st record hence 'N'. Even if there is one new number then Pull='N'. If all the numbers(Codes) of Claim_id='N' matches with the Codes of Claim_id='Y' then only Pull='Y'. I am populating the Pull column looking at member_id, claim_id and codes.

I am getting not the desired result with above query.

Comment: This is a horrible table design violating 1NF. Is there a known maximum number of codes?

Comment: I don't understand your query at all.  It looks to me like your 2 unions are all going to return the same set of rows.  Are you maybe trying to compare a row to the "previous" row?

Comment: Yes, comparing the codes of those with claim_id='N' with claim_id='Y'

Comment: There is no known maximum number of codes

Comment: Is there function to use instead of Oreplace or it can be done other ways